# Selenium Error: Element not interactable (coockie and other pop up)

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, inspect

I am trying to press a button with selenium because afterwards I need to inspect the full html of the website. This is the code that I am using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/audi/a4-allroad')
time.sleep(10)
html = driver.find_element_by_id('btnallestimenti')
html.click()
```

But I get this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

when the page is open there are cookies and other things that shows up, is there a way to block all of them so that I can work on the html?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This code works if I manually close the cookies and the second pop-up that I get!

Comment: Is your issue got resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the "cookies" banner is an HTML element itself and it contains a "Close" ("Chiudi") button that can be clicked.

If you inspect the page source you will find this code that relates to that button:

```
<button type="button" class="iubenda-cs-close-btn" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-pressed="false" style="font-size:16px!important;">Chiudi</button>
```

Your script needs to be modified to search the element by visible text (using the XPath) and click it to close the banner:

```
close_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Chiudi']")

close_button.click()
```

I can see that this kind of banner appears 2 times (one for cookies one for "Informativa") but once you click this one away you are redirected to the right page.

Of course you will need to test your script and adjust it to the page's behavior.

Also, be aware that every time the pages change because the devs change it your script will break and you will need to re-adjust it.

### EDIT

#### Posting here the full code, try to use it and continue from here:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/audi/a4-allroad")
time.sleep(6)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accetta']").click()
time.sleep(6)

driver.switch_to.frame("promo-premium-iframe")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Non sono interessato']").click()
time.sleep(6)

driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.find_element_by_id("btnallestimenti").click()

input()
```

Comment: Hey I am trying to make it works, I substitute 'Chiudi' with 'Accetta' - But still the second pop-up is coming... any idea how to solve that? Anyway, I will upvote for sure you have been already of help

Comment: @LuigiModica repeat the code for the second popup and it should work, basically you search for the desired button once again and click it.

Comment: I mean the white pop-up at the middle of the page, where there is written at the bottom of it "Non sono interessato" , which means "not interested"
Sorry for bothering but in this way you would solve lots of my thesis problem..

Comment: Try this: 
`driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn zaux-btn-1 zaux-btn-1--txtred1 closePromo').click()` after you close the cookies popup. Put `time.sleep(8)`  in between the 2 commands (remember to `import time`)

Comment: Unfortunately it did not worked..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to accept the cookie and proceed further, check the below lines of code.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,"ChromeDriver_Path")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.quattroruote.it/listino/audi/a4-allroad')
sleep(10)

cookie_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Accetta']")
cookie_btn.click()
sleep(3)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"promo-premium-iframe")))
register_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Accedi o Registrati']")
register_btn.click()
```

Iframe available so just switched to the iframe, tried the to perform the registration.